# Expo client restart because of DocumentPicker

Tags: react-native, expo

**Expo** client app reload/**restart** after selecting file via **DocumentPicker**!

Expo SDK Version: **32.0.0**

Sample code trying to run, https://snack.expo.io/HkuSxz6Sf

It doesn't provide an error either, it just restarts again!

Answer (score 0):

Please add the code below

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
  }
```

Comment: Hey Thanks,
But for DocumentPicker do I need that permission?
I added and as usual no outcome.

Comment: What simulator are you using? android? Ios?

Comment: Using my android phone(Meizu M3s) with expo client app as a simulator.

Comment: The cord is working perfectly well on my cell phone.